# Writing .hex file to Internal FlashROM of 8051 microcontroller using SPI bus

Tags: embedded, 8051

I am doing a firmware upgrade using SPI bus on EEPROM as well as Internal ROM of 8051, basically writing a .hex file on both these memory devices.I am able to see .hex file written there.I am able to see slave and master are communicating properly, but not able to write anything on my memory devices.

If you have suggestions and if you have faced similar problems, please let me know where is the actual problem.

Any inputs would be welcomed.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: You might like to explain what you have done, post your code, specify the hardware you're using, give examples of what you can & can't see / what is & isn't happening, what you've tried, etc.

One obvious thing is that .hex files are ASCII representations of raw data, so need some translation, some people forget this...

Comment: Most reprogrammable memory devices require some sequence of operations to unlock them before you can write.  Are you sending the correct commands?

Comment: My SPI EEprom chip is AT25128, and in that i have kept the WP(bar) pin
always high, that means i can write the data anything.I have used the code from below mentioned link(spi-test.c):
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/ltib/2010-11/msg00010.html
for my SPI EEprom. when i am running the code for i have getting the status register value : 0x02, that means i can write the data on that chip anytime. Please correct if something wrong i am doing.

Comment: Do i need to convert that .hex file into some other format, to write it onto EEprom. In my case my master is "ARM(32bit processor)" and target is Internal ROM of 8051 controller.

Comment: My SPI bus is of 8Mhz, still when i am writing data, it is taking 15 minutes to write a file of 26 kb size on 128 KB EEprom.

Comment: And my .hex file is in RFS and i am writing that file using SPI bus to EEprom of slave device.

Answer (score 1):

I think more information will likely be required.  In any case, here a few pitfalls I could see:

- Hex Files are not necessarily memory images.  The 8051s I've worked with usually use Intel Hex which is an ASCII format that describes the memory.  The format is well documented [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX)
- If you're having trouble writing to the EEPROM, you may not be writing the proper instructions.  Typically, SPI EEPROM will be Byte addressed, but still has paging internally.  You should start your writes on a Page boundary and write the whole page, then issue another write command, etc.  By convention if you overrun a page, or start in the middle of a page it will loop around.  So if your page is 8 bytes long, and you start writing 0-7 starting at index 4, you'll get:

  ```
  Page Start: Index 0 = 4
              Index 1 = 5
              Index 2 = 6
              Index 3 = 7
              Index 4 = 0
              Index 5 = 1
              Index 6 = 2
              Index 7 = 3
  ```

  - Most EEPROMs have locking mechanisms to prevent accidental writes once they are finalized.  If the lock has been set, you will need to write an unlocking method (this will be detailed in the data sheet if it has it)

To further help you, please reference part numbers and better yet Data Sheets if you can.

Comment: @SCM: 1. Yes, my file is in that format itself.In fact i have also checked the link mentioned by you.
2. My page size is mentioned in Data sheet is 64 bytes, but i am 128 bytes for my usage, is i am doing something wrong.
3. I don't have any locking mechanism, just i have made my WP(bar) pin HIGH for writing data. My chip is AT25128 SPI EEprom.

Comment: @SCM: 1. Yes, my file is in that format itself.In fact i have also checked the link mentioned by you.
2. My page size is mentioned in Data sheet is 64 bytes, but i am 128 bytes for my usage, is i am doing something wrong?
3. Is the file needs to be converted into some other format instead of .hex as it is having various which we are not writing on EEprom e.g address, record type, checksum etc.I am using C for programming on Linux OS.Please provide your inputs.